# Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration:

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I'm new to creating Facebook applications, but I have years of experience with php.   I've created a facebook app and have the appid & secret code.

I've copied the code from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login/5.0.0 and changed the pertinent information to match my account.

However, when I go to the login.php page on my live site, I get an error "*Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.*"

At my develops.facebook.com page, I have set:

```
Display Name: P3 Live
Namespace: [blank]
App Domains: p3live.com
Contact Email: [to my email address]

Site url to 'http://www.p3live.com/facebook'.   

On Advanced:
Native or desktop app: Yes
Is App Secret embedded in the client: No

Contains Alcohol:No
Age Restriction: 13+
Social Discovery: Yes
Country Restricted: No

Server IP Whitelist: [blank]
Update Setting IP Whitelist: [blank]
Update Notification Email: [my email address]
Require App Secret: No
Require 2 Factor Reauthorization: No
Allow API Access to App Settings: Yes

Client OAuth Login: Yes
Web OAuth Login: No
Embedded Browser OAuth Login: No
Force Web OAuth Reauthentication: No

Valid OAuth redirect URIs:
http://www.p3live.com/facebook/login.php
http://www.p3live.com/facebook/fb-callback.php

Login from Devices: No
```

As I said, I'm new to the facebook integration and we are looking to have our app be able to post to someones wall.   But first I'm just trying to get the application to login a user if they are not logged in.

I was able to get this to work with Javascript, but I want it to use the PHP SDK 5.

Any help (and advice for settings) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Web OAuth Login: No` – where from are you trying to login again …?

Comment: www.p3live.com/facebook/login.php    Even with Web OAuth Login: Yes, I still had the same error.

Comment: Also try setting `Native or desktop app` to No – you have a web app here, so it’s not native or desktop.

Comment: In App domains Add this also www.p3live.com

Answer (score 0):

You seem to pass in a wrong *redirect_uri*. In your settings you say that only *http://www.p3live.com/facebook/login.php* and *http://www.p3live.com/facebook/fb-callback.php* are valid, however, in your code you set the `redirect_uri` to `http://www.p3live.com/fb-callback.php`, which is not valid as per your settings.

If you change that to `http://www.p3live.com/facebook/fb-callback.php` it should work.